# TypeError: 'Interval' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
# Definition for an interval.
# class Interval:
#     def __init__(self, s=0, e=0):
#         self.start = s
#         self.end = e

class Solution:
    def merge(self, intervals):
        """
        :type intervals: List[Interval]
        :rtype: List[Interval]
        """

        out = []  
        for i in sorted(intervals, key=lambda i: i.start):
            if out and i.start <= out[-1].end:
                out[-1].end = max(out[-1].end, i.end)
            else:
                out += i
        return out
```

for the second last line, out += i, I got this error:
'Interval' object is not iterable.

I believe add a comma after it would works:

out += i,

but I don't know why, could anyone explain it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to add a single item to the end of a list, you typically use `append`.

```
out.append(i)
```

You can also extend your list by adding iterables or sequences of elements (like lists and tuples) using `+=`.

`i` isn't a sequence, so `out += i` does not work.

But `i,` is a sequence. It is a tuple containing `i`.

So

```
out += i,
```

does work. It's the same as if you had written

```
out += (i,)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation!